# django not loading template

Tags: django, django-templates

Maybe it's something I'm missing, but for some reason, django isn't looking for the template in the right place. I've included the contact/templates folder in the TEMPLATE_DIRS, and the app in the INSTALLED_APPS, but still, when I visit the URL, it checks for the contact.html in every other directory I have listed in the settings file, accept for the one where it's located. I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error. Are there maybe python shell commands I could use to diagnose the problem?

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
    '/mysite/contact/templates', #does not search this one
    '/mysite/liquor/templates', #searches this one
    '/mysite/store/templates', #searches this one
    '/mysite/order/templates', #searches this one
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    # theme
    "pinax_theme_bootstrap",
    "django_forms_bootstrap",

    # external
    "account",
    "metron",
    "eventlog",
    "paypal.standard.ipn",
    "djangojs",
    "django_tables2",
    "django_filters",

    # project
    "contact",
    "mysite",
    "liquor",
    "store",
    "order",
]
```

Comment: You have added `contact/templates` in the settings but in question you are saying template is in `contact/template` (without _'s'_). Is that typo here or your actual problem?

Comment: @Rohan, nope that's just a typo on here. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

`django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader`

listed in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting

Failing that, install `django-extensions` and use the `find_template` management command to debug the issue.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

E.g. if you're trying to use index.html

```
python manage.py find_template index.html
```

Comment: TEMPLATE_LOADERS is listed, and I tried using the django-extensions, where it point's to the html file's location just fine. However, the site still won't look for it in that folder.